# How do I count all instances of a phrase to the left of the current cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

So I want to use a formula to count every time a phrase to the left of a cell is used in a specific column, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The formula I'm trying right now is this:

=countif(AE1:AE, "=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))")

I'm guessing the problem is that it thinks the formula is the text I'm looking for, not that it's an actual formula, but I'm not sure how to fix that, or of it's even possible to fix?

Would prefer a solution I can easily copy paste into multiple cells n not have to modify a whole lot.

EDIT: Here's an example:

[Here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puXqV.png) I'm trying to count the number of times each word that's next to a "formula" appears in Column A...

[...and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C38q.png) is what I'd want the result to be.

(I'm on mobile, if that affects anything.)

Comment: Could you please add a small example of a sheet and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: @cyberbrain I added example images! I hope they help

Comment: Please split your question, only one problem per question.

Comment: @cyberbrain Did so, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually quite close to the solution, just leave out the `"= "` wrapper of your inner formula:

`=COUNTIF(AE:AE, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))`

should do what you need, if I understood the problem correctly.

But if you are copy-pasting only inside the sheet, formulas are adapted to the target, so you could do much easier:

`=COUNTIF(AE:AE,AE1)`

If you insert this formula into cell AF1 and copy it from there, the reference will automatically be adapted. If you don't want to adapt a part of the reference prepend it with `$`, e.g.

`=COUNTIF(AE:AE, $AE1)`

will never change the column of the second parameter (`AE`), while

`=COUNTIF(AE:AE, AE$1)`

will never change the row number of the second parameter (`1`). You can combine the row and column fixation.

Comment: The first formula works great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A7, A2:A7))
```

[image]

---

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A1:A="")+REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "dog|pig|cat"),,COUNTIF(A1:A, A1:A)))
```

[image]